# How do I plot different trials with separate lines with equal styles using FacetGrid in seaborn?

Tags: pandas, seaborn, facet-grid, line-plot

My pandas dataset has velocity curves for different trials of an experiment and for different conditions ('shifts'). I want to plot the velocity lines for each trial in the same facet per condition, but without specifying that I want the trials to influence a style they are just plotted in one continuous line, where the end of the first is connected to the start of the second line, and so on. This also means I can't use alpha values to see where the velocity curves are most dense, because it's just one big line. Is there a way to separate them?

[this is what it looks like without separation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMndS.png)

[this is what it's supposed to look like, just not with different hues for each line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJyjg.png)

This is the code I used for the second example

```
grid = sns.FacetGrid(half_second_df, col='shift', hue='trial', col_wrap=3)
grid.map(plt.plot, 't_rel_sacc', 'yaw_velo', linewidth=0.5, alpha=0.3)
```

Comment: I don't think I understand this. Do you want to separate the lines or not?

Comment: I want one line per trial, which amounts to 20 lines per facet. They are supposed to have the same color in every facet. But if I don't put `hue='trial'` in, all 20 lines for each facet are drawn as one long line. You can see the thick bar where all the end points connect to the next start point, those lines should not appear at all

Comment: What about `color="blue"`? Or which ever color you favour?

Comment: well that is kind of cheating, telling the FacetGrid to divide trials by hue and then overriding color with a separate argument. This works only in this specific case, what if I want the lines to be colored by condition, then I have the same problem again. I might open an issue for this

Comment: What condition would that be? Note that it is really hard to help here without a complete example.

Comment: the condition is just a column of the DataFrame, in this case `shift`. Seaborn makes different facets by splitting into groups using the given column names. The problem with the line plot is that if you don't give a column name by which to split lines into different styles, one continuous line is plotted. This doesn't make sense if there is a column, in my case `trial`, which separates different lines. For line plots, being split into separate lines is also a kind of 'style' I would argue

Comment: So you want the first column to have red lines and the second column to have green lines? (Again, a complete example would help keeping the comments short, and eventually allow for an answer to be given.)